# Extract strings based on custom list of items

Tags: python, pandas, string

Say we have this df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['hair color other family, friends ', 'family, friends hair color']})

    a
0   hair color other family, friends
1   family, friends hair color
```

I want to extract strings using my own list of items:

```
items = ['hair color', 'other', 'family, friends']
```

I want to do this because there are **no consistent delimiter or pattern** in the raw data.

Desired output:

```
import numpy as np
desired_output = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['hair color other family, friends ', 'family, friends hair color'],
                                   'hair color': ['hair color', 'hair color'],
                                   'other': ['other', np.nan],
                                   'family, friends': ['family, friends', 'family, friends']
                                  })


                                  a     hair color  other   family, friends
0   hair color other family, friends    hair color  other   family, friends
1   family, friends hair color          hair color  NaN     family, friends
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can craft a regex to use with [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html):

```
import re

regex = '|'.join([f'({re.escape(i)})' for i in items])
# '(hair\\ color)|(other)|(family,\\ friends)'

df.join(df['a'].str.extractall(regex)
                   .set_axis(items, axis=1)
                   .groupby(level=0).first())
```

output:

```
                                   a  hair color  other  family, friends
0  hair color other family, friends   hair color  other  family, friends
1         family, friends hair color  hair color   None  family, friends
```

##### update:

```
df.join(df['a'].str.extractall(regex)
                   .set_axis(items, axis=1)
                   .groupby(level=0).first()
                   .add_prefix('item1_')
                   .replace({None: np.nan})
       )
```

output:

```
                                   a item1_hair color item1_other item1_family, friends
0  hair color other family, friends        hair color       other       family, friends
1         family, friends hair color       hair color         NaN       family, friends
```

Comment: Amazing. Two questions, if I may: (1) How do I add a prefix to new columns names? For example, item1_hair color, item1_other, etc. I need this because I need to repeat operation for other variables, which have same items, and your solution would result in columns with same names (2) How do I generate np.nan instead of None?

Comment: (1) You can use `add_prefix('item_')` before joining, (2) `.replace({None: np.nan})`